# AngularJS $http.delete not working in Azure App Service

Tags: angularjs, azure

A follow-up on a similar question I posted yesterday. I am trying to delete data from a table in Azure App service. This is my function in my Angular file.

```
function delName(user) {
 //$scope.categories.push(user);
 alert("about to delete. Action cannot be undone. Continue?")
 $http.delete('https://test-evangelists-1.azurewebsites.net/tables/people', user, config)
   .then(function (res) {
       $scope.getNames();
   });
}
```

Then I added an HTML button:

```
<button id="btn-del-evangelist" class="btn btn-default btn" ng-click="delName(user);">Delete User</button>
```

This is the value of my headers variable:

```
var config = {
    headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
        'ZUMO-API-VERSION': '2.0.0'
    }
};
```

But when I tried to run it, the console returns the following error:

[image]

which states that the header for ZUMO-API-VERSION must be specified.

Below is my code for GET and POST

**GET:**

```
    function getNames() {
      $http.get('https://test-evangelists-1.azurewebsites.net/tables/people', config)
   .then(function (res) {
       console.log(res);
       $scope.people = res.data;
   });
  }
```

**POST**

```
 function addName(user){
     //$scope.categories.push(user);
     alert("about to post!")
     $http.post('https://test-evangelists-1.azurewebsites.net/tables/people', user, config)
       .then(function (res) {
           $scope.getNames();
       });
 }
```

Since I have already specified the header in my variable, I wonder what can be wrong here. Any help will be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
I figured out that the Id must be appended to the URL before I can perform delete. However, I need to run a GET to retrieve the ID given the parameters but I am still encountering errors when getting the ID.

This is now my Delete function

```
 function delName(user) {

     alert("About to delete. Action cannot be undone. Continue?")
     var retrievedId = "";

     $http.get('https://test-evangelists-1.azurewebsites.net/tables/people', {
         params: { name: user.name, location: user.location },
         headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'ZUMO-API-VERSION': '2.0.0' }
     })
        .then(function (res) {
            retrievedId = res.id;
            alert(retrievedId);
        });


     $http.delete('https://test-evangelists-1.azurewebsites.net/tables/people/' + retrievedId, config)
       .then(function (res) {
           $scope.getNames();
       });

 }
```

Does anyone know what is wrong in the GET command when getting the ID?

**UPDATE 2:** I have written instead an Web Method (asmx) that will connect to SQL server to retrieve the ID passing the needed parameters. The ID will be returned as a string literal but in JSON format. Then I called JSON.parse to parse the string into JSON object then assigned the ID to a variable to which I appended in the URL. –

This is now my Delete function after I have written the Web Method.

```
 function delName(user) {
        var confirmres = confirm("You are about to delete this record. Action cannot be undone. Continue?");
        var retrievedId = "";

        if (confirmres == true) {
            //get the ID via web service
            $http.get('\\angular\\EvangelistsWebService.asmx/GetId', {
                params: { name: user.name, location: user.location },
                headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'ZUMO-API-VERSION': '2.0.0' },
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
            })
               .then(function (res) {
                   $scope.retData = res.data;
                   var obj = JSON.parse($scope.retData);
                   angular.forEach(obj, function (item) {
                       if (item.length == 0)
                           alert('No data found');
                       else {
                           //perform delete after getting the ID and append it to url
                           $http.delete('https://test-evangelists-1.azurewebsites.net/tables/people/' + item.id, config)
                             .then(function (res) {
                                 $scope.getNames();
                             });
                           alert(item.id + ' deleted');
                       }
                   });
               });
        }
    }
```

That is one way that I have learned on how to call HTTP DELETE on AngularJS. But I don't know if that is the optimal one. In any case, that works for me, unless there will be other suggestions.

Comment: Did you look at the developer console(network tab) to verify that the version was actually passed on the delete call?

Comment: I edited my code to ensure that the version is passed. However, I am getting this time an Error 500: "error": "Incorrect syntax near ';'. That is also the error when I run it in Postman.

Comment: Wild guess since there is no information on your server-side: You are trying to delete a part of the table by passing the user. To do this, you are injecting the user into some sort of sql query. Now you are unable to pass content to "delete" since delete only has one parameter and the user is now not passed. You would need to provide some more information if you need more help.

Comment: I updated my delete function based on what I have learned. See above.

Comment: How does your backend look like? Request looks fine at first glance

Comment: I have written instead an WebMethod (asmx) that will connect to SQL server to retrieve the ID passing the needed parameters. The ID will be returned as a string literal but in JSON format. Then I called JSON.parse to parse the string into JSON object then assigned the ID to a variable to which I appended in the URL.

Comment: Code can be found in my GitHub public repo: https://github.com/ABSECDTest/GitTestRepo/tree/master/angular

Comment: see updated answer

Answer (score 1):

`$http.delete` only has one parameter (config), not two (data, config).

[Delete API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#delete)

> `delete(url, [config]);`

vs.

[Post API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post)

> `post(url, data, [config]);`

---

**To your updated problem:**

To delete an item from your table, it appears the correct url is:

```
 /tables/tablename/:id
```

Note the `:` before id.